# iPhone, is it possible to put an actionSheet and the clickedButtonAtIndex event in a reusable class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to provide the same buttons and the same functionality in the `clickedButtonAtIndex` on several views, can I do this in a reusable class?

If so how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to encapsulate your actionsheet+delegate into a new class:

```
@interface MyActionSheet : NSObject <UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
    UIActionSheet* _actionSheet;
}

@end

@implementation MyActionSheet

- (id) initAndShowInView: (UIView*) view
{
    if ( (self = [super init] ) )
    {
        _actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: @"Hi There" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"done" destructiveButtonTitle: nil otherButtonTitles: @"button 1", @"button2", nil];
        [_actionSheet showInView:view];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // your logic here
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [_actionSheet release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

This could be expanded on to add the delegate methods you may need.  You'll need to make sure the object continues to live (keep a retain on it) while the actionsheet is visible - the actionsheet doesn't increment the ref count on its delegate...